# How to add arguments without key, to add only value to the body of ConnectionRequest

Tags: lwuit, codenameone

I want to add a Json object to ConnectionRequest as value without key. I know that if use standard addArgument(key,value) -

```
addArgument("json","{JsonObject}")
```

in the body of request will be

```
json={JsonObject}
```

But I need to add only JsonObject without key and "=" symbol.

```
{JsonObject}
```

Is there any standard solution?
One more question Is there any class in Lwuit to create JsonObject similar to json.org.me
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just override

```
protected void buildRequestBody(OutputStream os)
```

And write whatever you want into the output stream. Don't use the arguments this will replace them anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I've copied almost half of the methods of ConecctionReauest.class to a new class and override buildRequestBody to not to lose old functionality and to get what i wanted.